# Migrate from Angular 4.3.2 to angular 7.1.3. common, core, forms, http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular4-forms

Correcting all packages and updating common, core, forms, http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic and router via npm install latest is cumbersome. 
My team and I are working on an App in production Target DEVdependencies we are looking at must be compatible with

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.3.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.9",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^2.4.2",
    "npm-install-peers": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.33.1",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Comment: Refer to this link https://update.angular.io/

Comment: And this one: https://angular.io/cli/update, though it won't help much starting from v4, it will help with v6 + v7.

Comment: @DeborahK I have updated packages "@angular/cli" and "@angular/compiler-cli" to 7.1.3. and "rxjs" to 6. No errors so far. But "ng update @angular/core" gives 404 error.

Comment: @NirajPaudel I am using the link as well. Is migration from 4.3.2 to 7 not advisable?

Comment: You can update from 4 to 6 and then from 6 to 7.

Comment: @NirajPaudel doing it. I am receiving error during ng serve. It says "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be
found".. I tried updating angular-cli.json to angular.json. Gives error "  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project)."

Comment: can you confirm you have run the command ng server inside your project root or elsewhere? From the error you stated, it seems like you have run the command not in the project root.

Comment: @NirajPaudel Project root is valid. Needed to change the new angular.json file according to specifications of github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace. Also tsconfig.app.json. No build errors now. But Chrome console gives "ERROR in : Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property
of 'ng-template'". Still working on the resolution